# expected false to deeply equal true on postman

Tags: javascript, postman

I am trying to write a test to confirm that `"Active": true` and am struggling. Apologies in advance for sloppy code. This is what I have tried and I am getting `"AssertionError: expected false to deeply equal true"`

Here is my code and response body I am receiving.

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
for (i of jsonData.resources) {
var found = false;
var serviceID = pm.environment.get("serviceID");
for (i of jsonData.resources) {
    if (i.ID == serviceID) {
        if (i.Active == "true") {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
pm.expect(found).to.be.eql(true);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please include your response body as text so it's searchable by users in the future.

Comment: You're missing a `const` declaration on the loop variable `i` (twice - or actually you will need to use a different variable name on the inner loop)

Comment: Why are you looping `for (i of jsonData.resources)` twice?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking if `i.Active == "true"` but your data shows `i.Active` as a boolean, not a string (`true !== 'true'`).

Check for a boolean instead:

```
if (i.Active === true) {
  found = true;
  break;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I really appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work for what you're trying to do:

```
let jsonData = pm.response.json(),
     serviceID = pm.environment.get("serviceID");

_.each(jsonData.resources, (item) => {
    if (item.ID === serviceID) {
        pm.expect(item.Active).to.be.true
    }
});
```